# Definitive -- Get TableViewCell Images to Stop Flickering

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have struggled with this problem for AEONS, and I thought I finally came across the solution. But no. I am trying to make a tableview where the images are loaded into the correct cells and persisted, without flickering.

Here is my solution:

```
extension SearchViewController : BookDataProcessorDelegate  {

    func didFetchSmall(image: UIImage?, for indexPath: IndexPath, in tableView: UITableView) {
        if tableView == resultsTableView {
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? BookTableViewCell {
                cell.imageView?.image = image
            }
        }
    }

    func bookSearchDidFinish(with books: [Book]?) {
        self.books = books == nil ?  [] : Array(books!.prefix(MAX_BOOK_COUNT))
        resultsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension SearchViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.books.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        BookDataProcessor.shared.fetchSmallImage(for: books[indexPath.row], at:indexPath, in:resultsTableView)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bookCell", for: indexPath) as! BookTableViewCell
        cell.authorLabel.text = books[indexPath.row].authorName?[0] ?? ""
        cell.titleLabel.text = books[indexPath.row].title ?? ""
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.indexPath = indexPath

        return cell
    }
```

It is pretty self explanatory. Basically, the `BookDataProcessor.shared.fetchSmallImage` triggers the `didFetchSmall` method, which should set the correct tableView cell. However, the cells flicker and disappear half the time. I am extremely interested to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hello, Alex. I can be wrong, but I do not understand why do you use tableView.cellForRow in didFetchSmall. You have cell already, and have to use it.
Your code in didFetchSmall calls tableView.cellForRow, witch called before willDisplay.

Comment: I want to find the correct cell to set the image. How else will I do this?

Comment: Yep, my bad.. I think you should check for a correct indexPath in the cell what you found in didFetchSmall. When you use 'tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)' IndexPath for the cell can be different already. Like: if let cell = ..., cell.indexPath == indexPath {} or get visibleCells and filter them by cell.indexPath.